# Reat native - How to fetch the CSV data from a link?

Tags: reactjs, database, react-native, url, mobile

1. The below Java code will extract the historical stock data from yahoo finance, but the output file is a CSV file that is being read and printed on the screen line by line.
2. But I want to do the same thing in React native.
3. It would be helpful if you guys can help me with the code for the same in react native.

   ```
    String link="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TSLA?period1=1563992913&period2=1595615313&interval=1d&events=history";

    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(inStream);


    String line =buf.readLine();
    while(line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line=buf.readLine();
    }
   ```

This is the data inside the link  :

Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume

2019-07-24,259.170013,266.070007,258.160004,264.880005,264.880005,11072800

2019-07-25,233.500000,234.500000,225.550003,228.820007,228.820007,22418300

2019-07-26,226.919998,230.259995,222.250000,228.039993,228.039993,10027700

2019-07-29,227.089996,235.940002,226.029999,235.770004,235.770004,9273300

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library such as [Papa parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) to do exactly this. It will also parse the data for you.

If we take the example from [here](https://www.papaparse.com/#remote-files), you could do something like this (assuming you would also like to print the data to the console):

```
import Papa from "papaparse"

const link = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TSLA?period1=1563992913&period2=1595615313&interval=1d&events=history"

Papa.parse(link, {
    download: true,
    complete: results => console.log(results),
})
```

Comment: Maybe you can create/show a small example to make your answer valuable